# extracting data from json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

## I am fetching the responses for the matching pattern, but the output results in else part only even though if condition satisfies. If I discard the else part my output is obtained as required.

```
import numpy    
import random
import json     


with open("intents.json") as file:  
    data = json.load(file)  

for intent in data["intents"]:  
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:  
        if "Hi" in intent["patterns"]:    
            w=intent["responses"]  
        else:  
            w=["Not found in pattern"]  
print(random.choice(w))
```

json link obtained from:
https://techwithtim.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/json-file.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, your both loops should break when your condition satisfies. You are not doing that so the problem may have arrived:

```
import random
import json     


with open("intents.json") as file:  
    data = json.load(file)  

for intent in data["intents"]:  
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:  
        if "Hi" in intent["patterns"]:    
            w=intent["responses"]  
            flag = 0
            break
        else:  
            w=["Not found in pattern"]  
    if flag == 0:
        break
print(random.choice(w))
```

I have used flag to indicate that inner loop has stopped.

Comment: hi Jeni, thanks but this works for first tag only, if i try passing values from pattern from tag other than greetings it skips the if statement again.   
```with open("intents.json") as file:  
    data = json.load(file)  
b=input("enter something") 
for intent in data["intents"]:  
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:  
        if  b.lower() in intent["patterns"]:    
            w=intent["responses"]  
            flag = 0
            break
        else:  
            w=["Not found in pattern"]  
    if flag == 0:
        break
print(random.choice(w))```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an error in your program. I believe it should be like this:

```py
import random
import json     


with open("intents.json") as file:  
    data = json.load(file)  

for intent in data["intents"]:  
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:  
        if "Hi" in pattern: ## Change 1 intent["patterns"] -- for --> pattern 
            w = pattern  ## Change 2 intent["patterns"] -- for --> pattern
            break ## Change 3 (Not sure about this one)
        else:  
            w = ["Not found in pattern"]  
print(random.choice(w))
```

I am not sure, if the `break` line should go in your script, I may think that is the most logical as you already found your pattern and you are printing the result at the end of the loop.

Comment: Hi Enrique, in the condition am searching "Hi"  matches the pattern key,ill be choosing the random responses from json associated under the tag. in which "Hi" is present. so eventually if hi is found then the code must return the either of the following from json.. "responses": ["Hello, thanks for visiting", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],